# Uploading files to google cloud storage <HttpError 403 "Insufficient Permission">

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am following the example python code for uploading and downloading files from google cloud storage.  I can download a file from the cloud without a problem, but using the same python file, when I attempt to upload a file I get the following error.  Any thoughts on what might be causing the permission error?

Thanks!
Adam

```
storage-file-transfer-json-python-master adamkglaser$ python chunked_transfer.py language_id.txt gs://adam_glaser_cloud_storage/test.txt
Authenticating...
Constructing Google Cloud Storage service...
Building upload request...
Uploading file: language_id.txt to bucket: adam_glaser_cloud_storage object: test.txt 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chunked_transfer.py", line 217, in <module>
    upload(sys.argv)
  File "chunked_transfer.py", line 148, in upload
    progress, response = request.next_chunk()
  File "/Users/adamkglaser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 132, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/adamkglaser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apiclient/http.py", line 808, in next_chunk
    raise ResumableUploadError(resp, content)
apiclient.errors.ResumableUploadError: <HttpError 403 "Insufficient Permission">
```

Comment: Are you referencing this example: https://github.com/yovadia12/storage-file-tranfer-json-python/blob/master/chunked_transfer.py ?

Comment: Yep, that is the one.  I can download files but for some reason cannot upload.  Not sure what is causing the permission error

Comment: Interesting. Did you fill in `client_secrets.json` with credentials that own that bucket?

Comment: Yes, I am puzzled by the issue.  They must be correct too, as I can download a file from the bucket, but not upload.  In any event, we are working behind a proxy at my work office (of which I know the details) , and the environment variables http_proxy, https_proxy etc. are all correctly set.

Comment: This morning I instead decided to pursue using gsutil.  When creating the configuration file, using gsutil config -b I was able to generate a working .boto file which also includes the proper proxy information.  This is working, not sure why this python example fails but I will just be working with gsutil moving forward!

Comment: I had the same problem. I ran `gcloud` with `--verbosity=debug` and I was able to get more info. Turns out I had requested the scopes during oauth.